# Error: "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties"?

Tags: c#, report, reporting

When I run my project,the following error message is displayed:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource.ReportDataSource(string, System.Collections.IEnumerable)' and 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource.ReportDataSource(string, System.Data.DataTable).

Why?

```
firstReportDBDataContext dc = new firstReportDBDataContext();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dsFirstReport.dtLoaiHangDataTable dt = new dsFirstReport.dtLoaiHangDataTable();
        var query = from a in dc.tblLoaiHangHoas
                    select a;
        foreach (tblLoaiHangHoa a in query)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(a.MaLoai, a.TenLoai);
        }
         this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsFirstReport_DataSet1",dt));
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

    }
```

Comment: what types does `dsFirstReport.dtLoaiHangDataTable` implement?

Comment: Does `dsFirstReport.dtLoaiHangDataTable` inherit from `DataTable` and implement `IEnumerable`?  If so, that's why it doesn't know which to choose.

Comment: dsFirstReport is dataset for table LoaiHang

Comment: can you post the implementation of dsFirstReportClass?

Answer (score 3):

From the error message, it's clear that the type `dsFirstReport.dtLoaiHangDataTable` inherits the `DataTable` type and implements `IEnumerable`.

You can resolve the ambiguity for the compiler by casting the parameter to one or the other. E.g.:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(
    new ReportDataSource("dsFirstReport_DataSet1", (IEnumerable)dt));
```