# Why is this crystal report report source load throws an ambiguous error?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

i have set the following code to load some data to a crystal report.

```
private void FrmReportViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataSet1.dtStudent4ReportDataTable dt = new DataSet1.dtStudent4ReportDataTable();


    DataSet1TableAdapters.dtStudent4ReportTableAdapter rta = new DataSet1TableAdapters.dtStudent4ReportTableAdapter();
    dt = rta.GetData(100001);
    ReportDocument rDoc = new ReportDocument();
    rDoc.Load(@"D:\SE\MS\Windows_apps\Projects\SMSV1-CURRENT\SMSV1\REPORTS\CRStudentEnrolment.rpt");
    rDoc.SetDataSource(dt);
    crv.ReportSource = rDoc;
}
```

when i check the values in dt variable it shows a record which it should be! but `rDoc.SetDataSource(dt)` throws an error at compile time

> Error 1   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(System.Collections.IEnumerable)'
>   and
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(System.Data.DataTable)'  D:\SE\MS\Windows_apps\Projects\SMSV1-CURRENT\SMSV1\FrmReportViewer.cs   30  13  SMSV1

[here is a youtube video on what happens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FG-1J0vgdLg&feature=youtu.be)

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: This is somewhat similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931794/error-the-call-is-ambiguous-between-the-following-methods-or-properties

Answer (score 0):

`dt` must be an object that both inherits from `System.Data.DataTable` and implements `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, so when you call `rDoc.SetDataSource(dt)`, the complier doesn't know which overload of `SetDataSource` to use.

You should cast `dt` to one of the two types, most likely `System.Data.DataTable`:

```
rDoc.SetDataSource((System.Data.DataTable)dt)
```